# 0 Character has a length of 4

Tags: character, string-length

I've been making a token app for my company, but i noticed something weird.

I copied a private key from my friend through whatsapp that was 64 characters long, but when i checked it on different online string length count services it says it was "67" characters.

We found out that the first '0' in the string was 4 characters long??

Here are the 2 private keys (they are fake so dont worry about security)
⁠⁠⁠0e6ec420ffcc38a1776e5fc2ac7d8a445a2e17c043f9979759d9ab5c10d57347 (67 length)
0e6ec420ffcc38a1776e5fc2ac7d8a445a2e17c043f9979759d9ab5c10d57347 (64 length)

Now im not sure if you can reproduce this with the given privatekeys because it may be that they are the same because this website changes it or something.

But can anyone explain why there are 2 different zero's with different lengths??
(btw the 4-char long zero doesnt have that line in the middle of it and the other one does have it)

Screenshot of the private keys:
[image: Different versions of the '0' character]

Comment: Start by checking what the actual _byte_ values are in a HEX editor.

Comment: @CBroe I used this online service for checking the hex value [link](http://codebeautify.org/string-hex-converter) and it said that the first "long" zero is '20602060206030' and the "normal" zero is '30' ...

Comment: Looks like you have a _normal_ zero in both cases - only one of them has the "word joiner" character in front of it three times. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2060/index.htm Some websites use such characters to control text flow, like where line breaks might occur. That this zero does not have a slash through it, might be a side effect, depend on the font or sth. like that.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the info! I just noticed that when i select the complete message in whatsapp web (dubble click on the message to select all), my '0' has the extra word joiner chars. When i select a part of the message including the '0' it does not copy the word joiner char.

Answer (score 0):

As CBroe said:

> Looks like you have a normal zero in both cases - only one of them has the "word joiner" character in front of it three times. [link](http://fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2060/index.htm) Some websites use such characters to control text flow, like where line breaks might occur. That this zero does not have a slash through it, might be a side effect, depend on the font or sth. like that.

Appearently when copying the **full** message from whatsapp web adds the so called "word joiner" characters at the beginning of the message.

When selecting only a part of the message it doesnt add these characters.